# Google Play Store - Acquisition Report & Flurry campaign links

Tags: flurry, google-play-console

We're currently using Flurry links to track the performance of our campaigns.

We're also using the Google Play Console Acquisition Report to track our results in general, as you can see here:

[google play store - acquisition report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEcE1.png)

In this case, would the Flurry links be included in third-party referrers?

Example of how a Flurry campaign link looks like (doesn't work because I changed the URL), which directs users to the store listing: https://ad.apps.fm/OkZ_Kuwfg9VJUqK7tNJZBV5KLoEjTszoNYfqOWJ38-sYDYehdio6Fq94ZO2QIerV-ArQd25g4TUTpzQQFtvGmGm78YegHkNWCxf

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, flurry would be in third party referrers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Nick! Another question (off-topic), is there a way to know what people were searching for - the ones who came through Play Store (organic)?

Also, is there a way to know the source/ medium of people who installed the app without visiting the store listing?